# MATLAB find array element and conditionally add to a constant

Tags: arrays, matlab, conditional-statements, addition

Given this array of angles:

```
  123.5280
  129.5280
  129.0130
  136.2960
  139.1640
  145.7430
  148.9800
  156.9080
  168.3440
  179.2340
    3.0840
    3.9720
```

I would like to identify those which are < 90 degrees

```
angles(angles < 90)

ans =

    3.0840
    3.9720
```

and add 180 to only those two having as a result

```
  123.5280
  129.5280
  129.0130
  136.2960
  139.1640
  145.7430
  148.9800
  156.9080
  168.3440
  179.2340
  183.0840
  183.9720
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `ind = angles < 90; angles(ind) = angles(ind) + 180;`

Comment: @Jubobs: There is nothing more to add. Make it an answer!

Comment: thanks @Jubobs--please add it as answer so I can give it a checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you are looking for is called (phase) unwrapping and there's a built in function [`unwrap`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) for that

```
res = unwrap(angles / 90 * pi) / pi * 90
```

Note that `unwrap` works in radians and for jumps of +/-pi and not 2*pi as you request, hence I'm intentionally scaling with `90 * pi` instead of `180 * pi`. Also see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196388/matlab-unwrap-function).

Answer (score 2):

```
angles(angles < 90) = angles(angles < 90) + 180
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in one line:

```
angles=angles+(angles<90)*180;
```